# How to initialize all the elements of an array to any specific value in java

Tags: java, arrays

In C and C++ we have the `memset()` function which can fulfill my wish. But in Java, how can I initialize all the elements to a specific value?

Whenever we write `int[] array = new int[10]`, this simply initializes an array of size 10 having all elements set to 0, but I just want to initialize all elements to something other than 0 (say, `-1`).

Otherwise I have to put a `for` loop just after the initialization, which ranges from index *0* to index *size − 1*, and inside that loop assign each element to the desired value, like this:

```java
int[] array = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = -1;
}
```

Am I going correct? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

If it's a primitive type, you can use `Arrays.fill()`:

```
Arrays.fill(array, -1);
```

[*Incidentally, `memset` in C or C++ is only of any real use for arrays of `char`.*]

Comment: I checked the source code of `Arrays.fill()`. It does the same thing.     `public static void fill(int[] a, int val) {`
        `for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)`
            `a[i] = val;`
    `}`

Comment: Yep.  As it should be.  Although I suspect the JIT might be smart enough to improve on the basic implementation.

Comment: I disagree. `memset` can also be used, and in fact is very useful, in integer arrays when you need to fill with `0` or `-1`, for example in DP problems.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - Not in a portable way.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *portable way*?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What if it is not primitive. I mean I need to initialize an array of BigDecimal and this solution does not work.

Comment: Just an FYI: You can use memset_pattern4, 8 & 16 for other integer sizes.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can you expand on the memset comment?
"[Incidentally, memset in C or C++ is only of any real use for arrays of char.]"

Comment: For 2D array specific value filling need iterating 1st layer array then fill it accordingly as beloe:
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        Arrays.fill(row, value);
    }

Answer (score 32):

There's also

```
int[] array = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

Comment: What if the size of array is unknown?

Answer (score 8):

It is also possible with Java 8 streams:

```
int[] a = IntStream.generate(() -> value).limit(count).toArray();
```

Probably, not the most efficient way to do the job, however.

Comment: This would also work for non-primitive types (`Stream.generate(() -> new Whatever("Hello World", 42)).limit(count).toArray();`), so is more flexible than Arrays.fill(). Not sure about the efficiency, though, as you say.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this if it's short:

`int[] array = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};`

but that gets bad for more than just a few.

Easier would be a `for` loop:

```
  int[] myArray = new int[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       myArray[i] = -1;
```

Edit:  I also like the `Arrays.fill()` option other people have mentioned.

Comment: is there any provision to initialize a 2-dimensional array? something like 
     int a[][]=new int[3][4]; 
     Arrays.fill(a,-1); 
so that all the 12 elements will be set with -1.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Comment: Could you please also give an example how this could look like?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Arrays.fill function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)?

Comment: Nope. I didn't use it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.fill(array, -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8, you can simply use `ncopies` of `Collections` class:

```
Object[] arrays = Collections.nCopies(size, object).stream().toArray();
```

In your case it will be:

```
Integer[] arrays = Collections.nCopies(10, Integer.valueOf(1)).stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296741/1387113) is a detailed answer of a similar case of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you can use  Arrays.fill(), The way you have it done also works though.

Comment: Ya. Even `Arrays.fill()` uses a `for` loop with index `0` to `size-1`. The same way, what i did. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Lists, you can use

```java
Collections.fill(arrayList, "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays class in java.utils has a method for that.

```
Arrays.fill(your_array, value_to_fill);
```

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of many of the existing answers.