# Creating 2D Array with given dimensions (Simple)

Tags: java, arrays

When creating a 2D array with say 5 rows and 5 columns, do you subtract one when initializing it?

```
String [][] array;
array = new String [4][4];
```

Would this create a 5 x 5 array since when you index it starts from 0? 
Also is there a way to set an array to blank, so for strings it would have all spots containing "" ?

Comment: The rules are no different than when creating a one-dimensional array. Do you subtract 1 when creating one of these?

Comment: **No**. Valid indices of an array are `0` to `length - 1`. Your `new String[4][4]` would have valid indices `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. That is a total of `4` (per dimension).

Comment: This is a good time for you to learn to experiment and Google thoroughly before asking. While elementary questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow, unresearched ones aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you should initialize array with the size you need.

To fill array with some default values, use `Arrays.fill`

```
String[][] arr = new String[5][5];
for (String[] ar : arr) {
    Arrays.fill(ar, "");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

output

```
[[, , , , ], [, , , , ], [, , , , ], [, , , , ], [, , , , ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to subtract one while initializing the 2D array as for the setting the values in the array to `""`

`Arrays.fill(array, "")`

[original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078899/4365969)

Answer (score 0):

String [][] array = new String[n][n]
where n is the size..so If u want to create 5*5 array..use array = new String[5][5] and index will vary from 0-4