# Returning values by repeating number n times of a value in array

Tags: java, arrays

It should print:

arrayBuilder(3, 7) should return the array [7, 7, 7].

So far I have:

```
public static int[] arrayBuilder(int len, int val) {
    int[] A = numbers();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    int val = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=len; i++) {
        val.append(len);
    }
    return val.toString();
}
```

Comment: What's `numbers()`? You can't do `append()` on an `int`; what are you trying to do here? Why are you returning a String?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize all the elements of an array to any specific value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078867/how-to-initialize-all-the-elements-of-an-array-to-any-specific-value-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have an `int` array of specified length and in the loop add that value always

```
public static int[] arrayBuilder(int len, int val) {
int[] A = new int[len];

for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    A[i]=val
  }
  return A;
}
```

**Case 2 :** As mentioned by @dave in comment you can use `Arrays.fill()`, First argument is array and second argument is the value that needs to fill in array

> public static void fill(int[] a, int val)

```
public static int[] arrayBuilder(int len, int val) {
int[] A = new int[len];

Arrays.fill(A,val);
return A;
}
```

I know your in learning stage, but providing more information so that you can grab more

Comment: Very clear and correct. The `for` loop could be replaced with [Arrays.fill(A, val)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-).

Comment: up updated @dave, i believe he is in learning stage

Comment: I agree and your first solution was appropriate for a beginner. I thought I'd add a library call in case others came along.

Answer (score -1):

This also should do the thing (with Java8+):

```
IntStream.range(0, len).map(i -> val).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: If the OP does not understand basic array instantiation, I think they will not understand this.

Comment: Perhaps this will be a motivation for OP to learn stream API :)

Comment: Is that before or after letting them know that a primitive `int` does not have an append method?

Comment: Also this returns a `List` not an `Array`

Comment: For an array one can use this: `IntStream.range(0, len).map(i -> val).toArray();`