# Initialize an array of references during declaration with a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor

I have a custom object `Point` and its constructor's parameters are given as `Point(int x, int y)`.

I want an array of ten distinct point, and each Point should be initialized to `(13, 27)` position, using a constructor.

```
Point[] points = new Point[10];
for (Point point : points) {
    point = new Point(13, 27);
}
```

I don't like the fact that in between the first line and the second line I have an array of `nulls`.

Can I somehow declare and initialize an array of references with my constructor, using one-liner?

The following works but we can see the problems with it:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] {
    new Point(10, 10),
    new Point(10, 10),
    new Point(10, 10),
    /// <7 more points omitted>
};
```

I am also wondering about a solution with `List` such as `ArrayList`.

In C++ I would do e.g.: `std::vector<Point> points{10, Point{13, 27}};`.

Edit: I need my array to hold references to 10 distinct (but equal) `Point` objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize all the elements of an array to any specific value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078867/how-to-initialize-all-the-elements-of-an-array-to-any-specific-value-in-java)

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan Unfortunately I am not dealing with primitives.

Comment: Can this help Point[] points = new Point[10];
        Arrays.fill(points, new Point(13, 27));

Comment: "but we can see the problems" What problems do you see?

Comment: @Joni Repetition?

Comment: Do you require 10 distinct `Point` objects (so you may modify each independently later), or will 10 references to the same `Point` object do?

Comment: 10 distinct references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use java streams to produce your array:

```
Point[] points = Stream.generate(() -> new Point(13,27)).limit(10).toArray(Point[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You require 10 distinct objects. You may go with [Jakob Em’s stream solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609506/5772882) or [the one by Govi S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609843/5772882). Or if you can live with the array holding `null` values temporarily:

```
    Point[] points = new Point[10];
    Arrays.setAll(points, index -> new Point(13, 27));
```

To me holding `null`s until initialized doesn’t appear to be that bad, and behind the scenes that happens in the stream solutions too.

**My original answer** gave you an array of 10 references to one and the same `Point` object. It may not be the code one would immediately expect to see for the task, but I think it’s well readable:

```
    Point[] points = Collections.nCopies(10, new Point(13, 27)).toArray(new Point[0]);
```

Since Java 11 a bit clearer still:

```
    Point[] points = Collections.nCopies(10, new Point(13, 27)).toArray(Point[]::new);
```

It also seems to me to be similar to your C++ way.